# Ymaps - как получить пути (path) мультимаршрута?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Делая что-то вроде

`let route = ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({ ... })
let paths = route.getActiveRoutes().getPaths() 
let path = paths[0]`

Comment: советую ознакомиться [ask]

Comment: Bharata - а что не так с постановкой вопроса?

Comment: Нет кода и дополнять надо вопрос, а не писать дополнения в ответах.

Comment: @Bharata как же нет кода, а 3 последние строчки не код? В ответах я написал не дополнение, а ответ на свой же вопрос :) "Как получить пути"

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ.
Путь получается через [multiRouter.MultiRouteModel](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRouteModel-docpage/)

`let path_0 = route.model.getRoutes()[0].getPaths()[0]`